# Why is that particular kind of sequence relevant to the question not repeat

Tags: contest-math

The following is a question from the IMO 2012 shortlist:

> Several positive integers are written in a row. Iteratively, Alice chooses two adjacent
>   numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x > y$ and $x$ is to the left of $y$, and replaces the pair $(x, y)$ by either
>   $(y + 1, x)$ or $(x − 1, x)$. Prove that she can perform only finitely many such iterations.

In a solution to this in page number 19, solution 3 in this document:

https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2012SL.pdf

It is stated that score sequences for the given sequence do not repeat. Why is that so?

> **Solution 3.** Let the current numbers be $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n$. Define the score $s_i$ of $a_i$ as the number of $a_j$’s that are less than $a_i$. Call the sequence $s_1, s_2,\ldots , s_n$ the *score sequence* of $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$.
>   Let us say that a sequence $x_1,\ldots , x_n$ dominates a sequence $y_1,\ldots , y_n$ if the first index $i$ with $x_i \neq y_i$ is such that $x_i < y_i$. We show that after each operation the new score sequence dominates the old one. **Score sequences do not repeat**, and there are finitely many possibilities for them, no more than $(n − 1)n$. Hence the process will terminate.
>
> Consider an operation that replaces $(x, y)$ by $(a, x)$, with $a = y + 1$ or $a = x − 1$. Suppose that $x$ was originally at position $i$. For each $j < i$ the score $s_j$ does not increase with the change because $y ≤ a$ and $x ≤ x$. If $s_j$ decreases for some $j < i$ then the new score sequence
>   dominates the old one. Assume that $s_j$ stays the same for all $j < i$ and consider $s_i$. Since $x > y$ and $y ≤ a ≤ x$, we see that $s_i$ decreases by at least $1$. This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domination as described is a transitive, non-reflexive property. Transitive means that if you have a chain $S_1\prec S_2\prec S_3\prec\cdots\prec S_k$ of sequences $S_i$, each one dominating the one before it (I just decided that $\prec$ would be a nice symbol to use for domination), then any sequence dominates *all* sequences before it in the chain, not just the one immidiately preceeding it. Non-reflexive means that no sequence dominates itself.

Put these two properties together, and you see that no sequence can appear twice in the chain. Of course, the transitive and non-reflexive properties mut be proven (transitive is usually described and proven using only a chain of length 3, and together with some almost trivial induction, that's enough to get what I described above). You also need to prove that whatever Alice does, she will produce such a chain, and that's what the second paragraph of the given solution focuses on.

Comment: Can you also please explain how are the bounds obtained? especially for the first solution that is given... the bounds for the other two solutions are quite simple...

Comment: @saisanjeev First of all, note that the exact value of any bound is irrelevant. It is the _existence_ of a bound which is important. But that being said, none of the $a_i$ can ever reach a higher value than $M$, which means that this special sum $S$ cannot ever get higher than $(1+2+3+\cdots +n)M$.